# APScheduler job is not starting as scheduled

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I'm trying to schedule a job to start every minute.
I have the scheduler defined in a `scheduler.py` script:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor


executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(10),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}
job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 5
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors=executors,job_defaults=job_defaults)
```

I initialize the scheduler in the `__init__.py` of the module like this:

```
from scheduler import scheduler

scheduler.start()
```

I want to start a scheduled job on a specific action, like this:

```
def AddJob():
    dbid = repository.database.GetDbid()
    job_id = 'CollectData_{0}'.format(dbid)
    scheduler.scheduled_job(func=TestScheduler(),
                            trigger='interval',
                            minutes=1,
                            id=job_id
                            )

def TestScheduler():
    for i in range(0,29):
        starttime = time()
        print "test"
        sleep(1.0 - ((time() - starttime) % 1.0))
```

First: when I'm executing the `AddJob()` function in the python console it starts to run as expected but not in the background, the console is blocked until the `TestScheduler` function ends after 30 seconds. I was expecting it to run in the background because it's a background scheduler.
Second: the job never starts again even when specifying a repeat interval of 1 minute.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I found the issue thanks to another thread. The wrong line is this:

```
scheduler.scheduled_job(func=TestScheduler(),
                            trigger='interval',
                            minutes=1,
                            id=job_id
                            )
```

I changed it to:

```
scheduler.add_job(func=TestScheduler,
                            trigger='interval',
                            minutes=1,
                            id=job_id
                            )
```

TestScheduler() becomes TestScheduler. Using TestScheduler() cause the result of the function TestScheduler() to be passed as an argument of the add_job().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem seems to be that you are initializing the scheduler inside the `__init__.py`, which doesn't seem to be the recommended way.
Code that exists in the `__init__.py` gets executed the first time a module from the specific folder gets imported. For example, imagine this structure:

```
my_module
|--__init__.py
|--test.py
```

with `__init__.py`:

```
from scheduler import scheduler

scheduler.start()
```

the `scheduler.start()` command gets executed when `from my_module import something`. So it either doesn't start at all from `__init__.py` or it starts many times (depending on the rest of your code!).

Another problem must be the use of `scheduler.scheduled_job()` method. If you read the documentation [on adding jobs](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/userguide.html#adding-jobs), you will observe that the recomended way is to use the `add_job()` method and not the `scheduled_job()` which is a decorator for convenience.

I would suggest something like this:

1. Keep `my_scheduler.py` as is.
2. Remove the `scheduler.start()` line from `__init__.py`.
3. Change your main file as follows:

   ```
   from my_scheduler import scheduler

   if not scheduler.running: # Clause suggested by @CyrilleMODIANO
       scheduler.start()

   def AddJob():
       dbid = repository.database.GetDbid()
       job_id = 'CollectData_{0}'.format(dbid)
       scheduler.add_job(
           func=TestScheduler,
           trigger='interval',
           minutes=1,
           id=job_id
       )

   ...
   ```

Comment: Added the solution to my post, removed the scheduler.start() from my init.py as per your recommendation.
Also added a clause to avoid restarting the scheduler if it is already running:

if not scheduler.running:
    scheduler.start()

Thanks

Comment: Good to know @CyrilleMODIANO If you like you can accept this answer :)

Comment: Well added your clause in there @CyrilleMODIANO

Comment: Does this work for production? With multiple workers and processes?