# Print time on APScheduler

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

How do you print the time with specific timezone used by APScheduler. I used an specific timezone for its BackgroundScheduler. When I used the 'cron' job to do a task on a specific time, it didn't went well. My suspicion is it's using a different time.

```
from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from mysql.connector import Error
from threading import Thread
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

import datetime
import time
import gspread
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(16),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
}

sched = BackgroundScheduler(timezone='Asia/Seoul', executors=executors)

def job_1():
    print("YES.")

def job_2():
    print("I'm working working...")
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

sched.add_job(job_1, 'cron', hour=17, minute=19)
sched.add_job(job_2, 'interval', seconds=10)



@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched.start()
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I needed to run job_1 on 5:19 on my Computer, but I guess I specified a timezone for APScheduler, so it did not execute. I want to know the current time the APSCheduler is using.

**UPDATE:**
When I used timezone=None,

```
sched = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=None, executors=executors)
```

It went well, it followed the time on my Computer. Now I just want to print the time of the specified timezone I used in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APScheduler job is not starting as scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389598/apscheduler-job-is-not-starting-as-scheduled)

Comment: Possible solution mentioned in link above: `sched.start()` inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` seems not to be the recommended way of starting the scheduler.

Comment: Doesn't seem it. The job works fine on the background and gets executed. The problem is just it will have mismatch if you specified some timezone maybe not the same as yours.

Comment: I added the solution they gave. Thanks! But it wasn't my question though.