# APScheduler print time

Tags: python, datetime, apscheduler

Hi I want to follow up my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074191/print-time-on-apscheduler). I got a solution in there to another problem. However I still want way around to this. Is there a way to print time from APScheduler?

I used:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

sched = BackgroundScheduler(timezone='America/Toronto', executors=executors)
```

From there I think the machine knows the time from its Timezone. I just needed to print it. Of course a solution could be the importing

```
import pytz
toronto = pytz.timezone('America/Toronto')
```

and get the time from that timezone. However, it duplicates, like yeah? So is there a way to do this with the APScheduler alone?

Comment: You mean like `sched.timezone`?

Comment: and print the current time.

Comment: How do you get the time from `pytz.timezone('America/Toronto')` because that should work with `sched.timezone`? One simple way is `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now(sched.timezone)`

Comment: Ohh wait let me try

Comment: WOW IT WORKED! You should have posted it as solution.